# Creating a custom TAB

Tags: android, tabs

I want to create a TAB-like activity.
The regular tab host has a specific design.
I want the tab buttons to be image views without any BG.
And by clicking on the image will just change the tab the regular way?

Maybe there is a way to do it in the regular TAB host?

[image]
I will be more specfici - the 2 buttons are actually 2 image views (also has 1 png for selected and 1 png for unselected). These 2 images are on the main BG (unlike the UI of the TAB Host). Upper to them there is the area (e.g. Frame) where my 2 activites should be ... Both activities has listview in it.

Comment: Closest solution I found - create 2 layouts with same common UI (iamges...) and just create a new activity with the layout (start the intent). I guess it is a bad idea....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these:
[Custom Android Tabs](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)

[Customize Android TabHost TabWidget](http://trace.adityalesmana.com/2010/08/customize-android-tabhost-tabwidget/)

Comment: Was not what I was looking for

Comment: @Yoav you should try first link, nobody is going to give you ready code. Try it by yourself atleast some code. Amy +1 for 1st link.

Comment: Closest solution I found - create 2 layouts with same common UI (iamges...) and just create a new activity with the layout (start the intent). I guess it is a bad idea....

Answer (score 1):

yes . you can do it . create yourView.xml and set this to `TabSpec.setIndicator(View)`

Comment: But this will be using the regulr TAB - in this way I have not found a way just to show the images as the TAB Buttons - like 2 image views on the main BG

Comment: can you b more specific then  2 image views on the main BG ? share screen image will be great if possible

Comment: It is 2 images on the main BG and they are on the buttom of the screen. On top of them should be the area (e.g. Frame) that I will have to change the activities inside

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be to create 2 separate views for the 2 tabs, then depending on which button (Tab1 or Tab2) is clicked, make the corresponding view visible and the other gone.
And of course you can give whatever background image to the buttons you want.

Comment: But if both layouts has listview in it? I think that it might have a problem since it will be only 1 list activity - and I would not want to inflate all again when changing between the views. Am I right?